# Is there any cryptographic-related graphics drawing package?

Tags: graphics, diagrams

For example, fig 4.7, 4.8 shows in

http://williamstallings.com/Extras/Security-Notes/lectures/blockA.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like a task TikZ could perfectly handle. [Those examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/block-diagrams/) could help you get started (I did not find any pure cryptographic example, but feel free to contribute once you've created yours!).

Answer (score 3):

http://www.di.ens.fr/~jean/latex_crypto/ has many examples of cryptographic diagrams in TikZ which you can use or adapt.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but this is an excellent resource:
https://www.iacr.org/authors/tikz/

Comment: Note that this answer refers to the new address of the repository mentionned in Max's answer